# Trying to read data and show it in table, from database where id is the last id that inserted CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the data from a database and show it in a table, but the data that I want to get is the data with the latest id that was inputted.

Here's my controller:

```
function index(){
        $data['input_pen'] = $this->m_read->m_baca()->result();
        $this->load->view('v_read',$data);
}
```

Here's my model:

```
public function m_baca() {
        $no_lahan = $this->db->insert_id();

        $this->db->select('input_pen.no_form, 
                   lahan.jenis, 
                   lahan.penggunaan, 
                   lahan.kondisi,
                   lahan.drainase');

        $this->db->from('input_pen');
        $this->db->join('lahan', 'input_pen.no_lahan = lahan.no_lahan');
        $this->db->where('lahan.no_lahan', $no_lahan);
        $q = $this->db->get();

        return $q;
}
```

and here's my view

```
<table border="1">
        <?php 
        $no = 1;
        foreach($input_pen as $p){ 
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $p->no_form ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $p->jenis ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $p->penggunaan ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $p->kondisi ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $p->drainase ?></td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

When I run this code, will display a blank view.

What do I do to get the latest id?

What is wrong?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: CodeIgniter's  `$this->db->insert_id();`  will only return an ID of an `insert()`

Comment: first of all check your sql query in mysql , is it proper works or any error on it ?????????

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help you out,
if your `lahan.no_lahan` column is a primary key and is autoincrement field then you can get the result of your query in the following way

```
$this->db->select('input_pen.no_form, 
               lahan.jenis, 
               lahan.penggunaan, 
               lahan.kondisi,
               lahan.drainase');

    $this->db->from('input_pen');
    $this->db->join('lahan', 'input_pen.no_lahan = lahan.no_lahan');
    $this->db->where('lahan.no_lahan', $no_lahan);
    $this->db->order_by('lahan.no_lahan', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit('1');
    $q = $this->db->get();
```

using order by your primary field and setting limit to 1, so you will always get the last record inserted in that table.

or the other thing you can do is, at the time where you are inserting the data in the table there you get the last inserted id something like this

```
function add_data($post_data){
$this->db->insert('input_pen', $post_data);
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
return  $insert_id;
}
```

Comment: nice suggestion!

Comment: where i defined variable $no_lahan? with using this? $no_lahan = $this->db->insert_id();

Comment: you have to define it where you are inserting the data in that table and make sure that your $no_lahan variable is accessible in the function where you are writing the select query.